# Trying to open a pop-up window but the url isn't working

Tags: html, href

```
<a href="examplewebsite.com" onclick="window.open('anewexample.com/index.html')">Click here</a>
```

When published and clicked, the link is www.examplewebsite.com/www.anewexample.com/index.html

Ive removed the href code and it doesnt work at all. If anyone can help, then im happy to listen.

Comment: Without even seeing you're links it is obvious the paths in your hyperlinks are incorrect

Comment: You should add http:// to your links

Comment: it added as a code.  <a href=http://"www.example.com/index.html"  onclick="window.open('www.youclickedhere')">Click here</a>

I KNOW ITS MISSING " BEFORE HTTP:// BUT OTHERWISE IT WAS POSTING AS CODE NOT AS I WANTED IT TO.

Comment: The point of posting it as code is so people can see it without having to edit your post.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a relative href instead of an absolute link...

try adding http:// at the beggining.

Make your questions more complete next time, by posting your code at least.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `<a>` tags , href must have `http://` before it. If it doesn't, the browser thinks you're reffering to a relative path. So add `http://` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You should try without onclick:

```
<a href="http://www.examplewebsite.com" target="_blank">Click here!</a>
```

Much easier this way.

Comment: Thanks for that, ive give it a try

Comment: After trying that, thats not what i am looking for. As i want it to open a new window as well as direct the first page to a different page.